# I keep getting a 'no match for call to' error

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


// Turns a digit between 1 and 9 into its english name
// Turn a number into its english name

string int_name(int n)
{

  string digit_name;
  {
    if (n == 1) return "one";
     else if (n == 2) return "two";
     else if (n == 3) return "three";
     else if (n == 4) return "four";
     else if (n == 5) return "five";
     else if (n == 6) return "six";
     else if (n == 7) return "seven";
     else if (n == 8) return "eight";
     else if (n == 9) return "nine";

    return "";
  }


  string teen_name;
  {
    if (n == 10) return "ten";
     else if (n == 11) return "eleven";
     else if (n == 12) return "twelve";
     else if (n == 13) return "thirteen";
     else if (n == 14) return "fourteen";
     else if (n == 14) return "fourteen";
     else if (n == 15) return "fifteen";
     else if (n == 16) return "sixteen";
     else if (n == 17) return "seventeen";
     else if (n == 18) return "eighteen";
     else if (n == 19) return "nineteen";

    return "";
  }


  string tens_name;
  {
    if (n == 2) return "twenty";
     else if (n == 3) return "thirty";
     else if (n == 4) return "forty";
     else if (n == 5) return "fifty";
     else if (n == 6) return "sixty";
     else if (n == 7) return "seventy";
     else if (n == 8) return "eighty";
     else if (n == 9) return "ninety";

    return "";
  }

  int c = n; // the part that still needs to be converted
  string r; // the return value

  if (c >= 1000)
  {
     r = int_name(c / 1000) + " thousand";
     c = c % 1000;
  }

  if (c >= 100)
  {
     r = r + " " + digit_name(c / 100) + " hundred";
     c = c % 100;
  }

  if (c >= 20)
  {
     r = r + " " + tens_name(c /10);
     c = c % 10;
  }

  if (c >= 10)
  {
     r = r + " " + teen_name(c);
     c = 0;
  }

  if (c > 0)
     r = r + " " + digit_name(c);

  return r;
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  cout << endl << endl;
  cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";
  cin >> n;
  cout << endl;
  cout << int_name(n);
  cout << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

I Keep getting this Error code:

> intname2.cpp: In function âstd::string
>   int_name(int)â:
>   intname2.cpp:74: error: no match for
>   call to â(std::string) (int)â
>   intname2.cpp:80: error: no match for
>   call to â(std::string) (int)â
>   intname2.cpp:86: error: no match for
>   call to â(std::string) (int&)â
>   intname2.cpp:91: error: no match for
>   call to â(std::string) (int&)â

Comment: Questions having a title that starts with *Please Help* and body containing poorly formatted source code are generally not appreciated on SO.

Comment: Do you by any chance think you are creating local functions? C++ does not have such things.

Comment: You really should read a C++ book.

Comment: well the original program had the srings declared outside the int_name function.. my professor wanted us to make it so we only use a int_name so we have to move them into it but idk how this is as close as ive gotten i am brand new to c++

Comment: @Timothy, I'm not sure what your teacher wants you to do here. What do you mean you have to move the functions into int_name? Please make sure you understand the requirements correctly... you can't move the body of one function into the body of another function.

Comment: (3) Write another version of program intname.cpp where
    you only have function int_name(int n), but NOT
    the other three functions digit_name, teen_name,
    and tens_name. What will your program look like?

    Get it to compile and run ...

    Hint: the bodies of funtions digit_name, teen_name
          and tens_name will need to appear within the
    body of int_name in the proper locations with proper
    namings of variables

Comment: @Timothy, I've updated my answer with some sample code...

Answer (score 3):

You are using `digit_name`, `teen_name`, etc as functions, when they are defined as variables.  If you want to use them like that, you need to define them before your `int_name` function like this:

```
string digit_name(int n)
{
 if (n == 1) return "one";
 else if (n == 2) return "two";
 else if (n == 3) return "three";
 else if (n == 4) return "four";
 else if (n == 5) return "five";
 else if (n == 6) return "six";
 else if (n == 7) return "seven";
 else if (n == 8) return "eight";
 else if (n == 9) return "nine";

 return "";
}
```

Comment: yeah thats what the oringinal program was paul but now our professor wants us to make it so the only thing we have is int_name and int_main she wants us to move the bodies into the int_name function somehow and thats where im getting lost

Answer (score 1):

Timothy, it looks like you're confused about the requirements of the assignment. Please make sure you understand the requirements, because at this stage it doesn't look like you know what's expected of you. You're trying to move the body of one function into the body of another function and that's simply not possible to do.

Please post the **exact words** that your teacher used in order for us to give you proper advice on the question.

<strike>Here are some tips for you:</strike>

- If your teacher has covered switch statements then use switch statements.
- Check if your teacher is not asking you to do function declarations.
- Check if your teacher is not asking you to put the functions in libraries (a header file and source file).

OK scrap the tips... given your teacher's requirements I think it might look a little bit like this:

```
string int_name(int n)
{
    int c = n; // the part that still needs to be converted
    string r; // the return value

    if (c >= 1000)
    {
        r = int_name(c / 1000) + " thousand";
        c = c % 1000;
    }

    if (c >= 100)
    {
        // If you have covered switch statements then it will look  like this
        string digitName;
        switch(c/100) // <- instead of calling digit_name(c/100), we call switch(c/100)
        {
            case 1:
                // assign the digit name
                digitName = "one";
                break;
            case 2:
                //... fill here with your own code
                break;
            case 3:
                //... fill here with your own code
                break;
            // write all the cases through 9
            default:
                digitName = "";
                break;
        }

        // in the result string use the digitName variable
        // instead of calling the digit_name function
        r = r + " " + digitName + " hundred";
        c = c % 100;
    }

    if (c >= 20)
    {
        r = r + " " + tens_name(c /10);
        c = c % 10;
    }

    if (c >= 10)
    {
        r = r + " " + teen_name(c);
        c = 0;
    }

    if (c > 0)
        r = r + " " + digit_name(c);

    return r;
}
```

Note that I'm using a switch statement, but if you your teacher hasn't shown you switch statements yet, then you can still use if/else statements:

```
string int_name(int n)
{
    int c = n; // the part that still needs to be converted
    string r; // the return value

    if (c >= 1000)
    {
        r = int_name(c / 1000) + " thousand";
        c = c % 1000;
    }

    if (c >= 100)
    {
        // declare a digitName
        string digitName;

        // declare a temporary value
        int temp = c/100;
        if(1 == temp)
        {
            // assign the digit name
            digitName = "one";
        }
        else if( 2 == temp )
        {
            digitName = "two";
        }
        else if( 3 == temp )
        {
            // fill in the rest
        }
        else if( 4 == temp )
        {
            // fill in the rest
        }
        // write all the other else if statements
        else
        {
            digitName = "":
        }

        // in the result string use the digitName variable
        // instead of calling the digit_name function
        r = r + " " + digitName + " hundred";
        c = c % 100;
    }

    if (c >= 20)
    {
        r = r + " " + tens_name(c /10);
        c = c % 10;
    }

    if (c >= 10)
    {
        r = r + " " + teen_name(c);
        c = 0;
    }

    if (c > 0)
        r = r + " " + digit_name(c);

    return r;
}
```

You're going to have to take the first example with `digit_name` and apply it to `tens_name` and `teen_name` functions.

**WARNING:**
In reality you don't want to repeat the same code and clutter a single function with a bunch of code that could be in its own function. You ALWAYS want to break out repeating code into functions... if she's asking you to repeat code when you can use functions then you should be concerned. Ask your teacher if this is what she **REALLY** wants you to do!

Comment: Why not make that a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: (3) Write another version of program intname.cpp where
    you only have function int_name(int n), but NOT
    the other three functions digit_name, teen_name,
    and tens_name. What will your program look like?

    Get it to compile and run ...

    Hint: the bodies of funtions digit_name, teen_name
          and tens_name will need to appear within the
    body of int_name in the proper locations with proper
    namings of variables

Comment: thats the assignment and the code i posted is my attempt at converting it i know its horrible our c++ book has nothing to help

Comment: so the _bodies_ of the functions will need appear within the body of int_name, not the function definitions + body.

Comment: @Timothy, I've updated my response with some sample code, but you should check with your teacher, because moving the bodies of the functions inside the body of int_name will produce some duplicate code which is a **bad practice** in programming.